# Is it possible in Google App Engine to update a datastore field according to the content of an email?

Tags: google-app-engine

For example, I have an object with a BooleanProperty() type, and my email contains two buttons YES and NO.

Is it possible to change the value of the property in my datastore, when the user click on one of the buttons in the email and send it back to my app?

Thank you.

Comment: Have the buttons in your email submit an HTTP request to your application with the ID of the entity to modify and the value of the type (true/false) as parameters.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. So my buttons would be in a form with some id, which I would send to my Python script, which would then do the datastore processing?

Comment: Yes. I don't see any other way of doing it.

Comment: Neither do I. All right, thanks!

Comment: I would not recormend placing an HTML form within an email. Email clients vary dramatically when it comes to HTML support and many will strip out forms as they don't really have any business being in an email. Use a regular `<a href="">` link in your email as your "button" that just links to a URL on your application

Comment: @Chris Er, forms in emails are pretty common practice. For instance, Google Apps lets you send forms attached to a spreadsheet to users, and they can answer them in their email client.

Comment: @nick, sure it can work but in my experience I would avoid it. Lots of big companies like to pre-process messages to "clean" them, I've seen antivirus software remove actions from forms, I've seen over the top "warnings" about submitting forms from email and IIRC outlook 2007 is terrible at displaying forms. Maybe things have improved but since it's so hard to test in the many variations and this use-case it is just not required, I'd skip it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do.

In my out going email I have two hyperlinks Yes and NO, which point to a servlet file like 
[Yes](/myServletFile?userResponse=Yes)

When the user clicks on the Yes link my servlet will read the userResponse and do the database store or update and then send to a confirm page via sendRedirect();